# To set the default value in the dropdown in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have component called **list** where i am displaying all my `customers` from an `api` in the dropdown as in below pic:

[image]

How  can i set 1st customer as default ? like this:

[image]

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-h9ev4t?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.html)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```
selectedCustomer = '01';
```

And in template use `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <h3>List</h3>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select 
      placeholder="Select Customer" 
      [(ngModel)]="selectedCustomer">
      <mat-option 
        *ngFor="let customer of customers" 
        [value]="customer.id" 
        (click)="selected($event, customer.id)">
        {{customer.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-skmsmq?file=src/app/list/list.component.ts) for your ref.